# How do I uninstall Avast Anti-Virus after accidentally deleting it from my CCleaner Uninstall Programs list?

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, uninstall

I went on CCleaner because I wanted to uninstall Avast Antivirus from my computer because theres too many programs running at start up and I already have the paid version (premium) of MalwareBytes installed so I dont need it.

I only installed it so that I could use the Boot-Time scan, as Malwarebytes does not have a Boot-Time scan to my knowledge.

But then, I accidentally deleted the Avast Antivirus entry from my Uninstall Programs list in CCleaner. And now it wont even show up on my Uninstall Programs list in Control Panel either. Yet it is still installed on my computer. How do I uninstall it now?

Comment: You can uninstall Avast by using the installer you used to install it.  You can also use the tool that Avast provides to uninstall their products.  **The problems you have experienced is the reason you should never used CCleaner or any program like it.**  If you end up trying the Avast tool to remove the product, and it does not work, be sure to update your question.  If it does work you should submit an answer indicating the tool does indeed work in this situation.

Comment: https://helpdeskgeek.com/free-tools-review/why-you-shouldnt-download-ccleaner-for-windows-anymore/

Comment: MalwareBytes isn't Anti-virus software. They exist as a catch to certain types of malware many AV products do not protect against, and they do not run in real time. Do not remove your AV thinking MBAM will protect you. They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a uninstaller at [Avast's website](https://www.avast.com/en-us/uninstall-utility).

Here are the steps:

> 1. Download `avastclear.exe` on your desktop
> 2. Start Windows in Safe Mode
> 3. Open (execute) the uninstall utility 1, If you installed Avast in a different folder than the default, browse for it. (Note: Be careful!
>      The content of any folder you choose will be deleted!)
> 4. Click REMOVE
> 5. Restart your computer